# How to clear dash figure with callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I've got a graph that I want to reset to the original state, seen in picture:
[image: the original state]

I tried this, as if I print the initial state of figure it says None.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph')
    )
])
           
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('click', 'clickedData')])
def myfun(x): 
    ...
    return None
```

But I get the error: Cannot read property 'layout' of null

What should I return so my new graph returns to original empty state?

Answer (score 5):

It should help to return empty figure: `fig = {}`.
In the callback just write `return {}` instead of `return None`.

Comment: No questions in answer please, they get misunderstood and flagged as "not an answer".

Answer (score 3):

You should return a `go.Figure` object since it will be placed into the `figure` property of the `dcc.Graph`. You can make empty figure by giving `x=[], y=[]` to the arguments of the `go.Figure`:

```py
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'), [Input('click', 'n_clicks')])
def myfun(n_clicks):
    if not n_clicks:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=[], y=[])])
    return fig
```

*(Full app code below)*

#### Before and after click

[image]
[image]

### Full app code

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 1, 2])])

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Test app'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure=fig),
    html.Button('Click to empty', id='click')
])


@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'), [Input('click', 'n_clicks')])
def myfun(n_clicks):
    if not n_clicks:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=[], y=[])])
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works to clear the figure however it changes the format. Is there a way to revert it back to the original format created by just 
html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id = 'graph')
    )
?

Comment: The callback will change everything inside the `figure` property. If you want to keep everything similar, use same function to create the figure initially to `dcc.Graph` and to create the empty figure in the callback. You can use whatever type of figure you want: scatterplot, barplot, ... etc.